# Get categories in the same order they are in the menu

Tags: wordpress, menu, categories

I'm getting stuck on a quite simple problem (I guess). I am trying to get categories within my template order the same way they are ordered in my main menu.

For information I'm using WP 3.0.4, french version.

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not an orthodox method, but we don't have a category sorting field so...

If you are not using the **Description** field of the categories, you could use this field as a sorting field. Say, introducing a single char from A to Z in admin, and use [get_categories()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories) or [wp_list_categories()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories) with the option `'orderby' => 'description'`, `'order' => 'ASC'/'DESC'`.

Or, if you do use this field, perhaps some creativity with first words would do it! Like "*A category for java articles*" instead of "*Java articles*"; "Bunch of PHP articles" instead of "PHP articles", etc.

Comment: I guess this will be the best answer for my problem so thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the wp_list_categories() function http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories

Use, the orderby parameter. To sort by name, use

```
<ul>
  <?php wp_list_categories('orderby=name'); ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but that was not exactly what I was expecting. I'd like the categories to be retrieved in the same order I've ordered them in my custom menu.

Comment: No, I think it's not possibile, unless you retrieve the menu from the database and filter out the other items that are not categories. Quick hack, but unmanageable, create a second menu only with the categories.